# When and how did Claude take a part of Ciel's soul?

Tags: black-butler

In the anime of *Kuroshitsuji* (*Black Butler*) season 2, Sebastian was at some point not able to consume Ciel's soul, because Claude had a part of it.

When did Claude manage to get it and how?

Comment: Hohoho, interesting. I can't recall these events in the manga :)

Comment: It needs to be noted that this event is anime only. It doesn't exist in the manga where the series originated from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not positive exactly what part you're talking about because it's been a while since I watched that part of the show, and your question is a bit vague.

Here's what happens:

Sebastian doesn't want to consume Ciel's soul as it is (as of the start of *Kuroshitsuji II*) because he doesn't remember taking his revenge, so his soul is incomplete. As such, Sebastian and Claude make a bargain to allow Ciel to take a second revenge, this time on Alois. Both think that, after the second revenge will happen, they will be able to get Ciel and consume his soul.

Claude then kills Alois and puts his soul in a ring.

Following that, from [this](http://kuroshitsuji.wikia.com/wiki/Claude_Faustus):

> It is shown that [Claude] is keeping a close eye on Sebastian and Ciel as they embark in another assignment from the Queen when Sebastian becomes occupied in a fight with William T. Spears, Ciel is arrested by the police who believe he's Alois Trancy and is identified by Hannah as Alois. Ciel is then tortured, which Claude and Hannah override. While Ciel is in a weak state after heavy and severe treatment Claude begins hypnotizing him and then places Alois's ring on Ciel's finger causing Alois's memories to mix in with Ciel's memories; this causes Ciel to believe that Sebastian was the cause for the death of his parents and his "brother," Luka Macken. When Sebastian finally reaches Ciel, Ciel pushes him away and refers to Claude as his butler. Claude then whispers to Ciel to order Sebastian to leave his sight, which Ciel does willfully. Claude then takes the weak and tired Ciel back to the Trancy mansion where he is warmly welcomed.

Comment: so, that's why his soul was incomplete? Because Ciel hadn't taken his revenge?

Comment: It's because Ciel lost his memories and didn't remember having taken his revenge.

Answer (score 0):

I think that moment is in the last episode of season 1 when there was a crow staring at them while Sebastian was going to take Ciel's soul. Then in season 2 episode 6, in the flashback of what happened that day, the said crow flew off with the spider on his face.

It's just my theory after re-watching *Kuroshitsuji*.

Answer (score 0):

Sebatian's contract with Ciel are cut-off because Sebastian lost his arm with the contract on, I think The contract are lost during the battle between Sebastian and Ash/Angela. So since the contract are lost, I guess other demons can steal Ciel's soul, and eat it.

Comment: Can you provide any sources (chapters or episodes, etc.) for this?